# Unix C socket server not accepting connections

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

Here's the deal, I'm writing a simple tcp socket server in C (with unix system calls) that I'm not able to get to accept connections.

From what I can tell, I get through the server initialization just fine, but when I try to connect to the port that I print out (see code below) it refuses as if nothing is there.

More to the point, when I netstat that port isn't even in use. I'm not throwing any errors with my current set up, I'm all dried up for ideas.

```
int main(){

    int sock_fd;
    int conn_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    socklen_t* serlen;
    socklen_t* clilen;
    clilen  = malloc(sizeof(socklen_t));
    serlen  = malloc(sizeof(socklen_t));
    *serlen = sizeof(serv_addr);
    *clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    /*=============================Create Socket=============================*/


        //Create Socket
        sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            if(sock_fd<0){
                fprintf(stderr,"error creating socket\n");
                exit(1);}

        //Initialize Server Address Struct
        bzero((char *) &serv_addr, *serlen);
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        serv_addr.sin_port = 0;

    /*=============================Bind Address==============================*/

        //Bind socket to an address
        if(bind(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,*serlen)<0){
            fprintf(stderr,"error binding\n");
            exit(1);}

        //Get socket data
        if(getsockname(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, serlen)<0){
            fprintf(stderr,"error with socket name");
            exit(1);}

    /*=============================Server Started============================*/

        //Listen for connections
        listen(sock_fd,32);

        //Print port
        printf("%i", serv_addr.sin_port);

        conn_fd = accept(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr,clilen);

        /**Do something exciting with my new connection**/

}
```

Comment: Did you check iptables & selinux?

Comment: Check if your firewall has blocked those ports.

Comment: checked and cleared. They're the ports that the kernel automatically assigned by requesting to bind the socket to '0' so I imagined this was the case, but it was worth checking again

Comment: What is output of this from your code: "printf("%i", serv_addr.sin_port);" ? also can you run netstat using your executable name i.e. #netstat -apn | grep a.out

Comment: it prints out random 4~5 digit integers, which I'm led to believe are free points automatically assigned by the kernel. (I also tried hard-coding some open ports in with the same result) And the netstat for the name and the port both come back empty

Comment: ok, where is your client code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

props to @askmish for inspiring this one

```
    //Print port
    printf("%i", serv_addr.sin_port);
```

becomes

```
    //Print port
    printf("%i", htons(serv_addr.sin_port));
```

Comment: Thank you dude, you have no idea how long I struggled to get the server to work, turns out this was the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Are you really trying to listen on port zero?  Try a high port number, preferably > 1024.  /etc/services will give a hint about free ports - but it only a set of comments, those port numbers are not enforced.

Edit:  another hint.  The port number should be in *network order*, so the assignment should use `htons()`.  It could be that the "random numbers" you are getting are simple numbers that appear garbled because you might be on a little-endian machine (like Intel).  When you print them, convert them back using `ntohs()`.

Comment: And if you are trying to listen on port zero ... I'm surprised `bind` succeeds

Comment: Hmm, I thought that binding to 0 (bind(2)) would automatically assign a port. I check to make sure this is happening when I call getsockname before listening to the socket descriptor. (i.e. good catch, but I verify that this is okay in the code)

Comment: @darkpbj where does it say that in the manual ? and if bind assigns some arbitrary port, how would you know which one to connect to ?

Comment: I'm looking through the manual right now, but in the mean time, I take my socket descriptor and feed it into getsockname() immediately after I bind, and check to make sure that something got put there.  
`printf("%i", serv_addr.sin_port);` 
serv_addr.sin_port was zero, and it keeps spitting out valid ports when I run it. I've done my diligence in the way of error checking, and I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with this particular method of letting the kernel select and open valid port.

Comment: to be totally thorough, I plugged a few random (read: open) ports into the code and recompiled a few times and got the same result. I'm doing something wrong, but the port isn't the problem

Comment: If the ports are open then you won't be able to bind to them.

Comment: @mux bind() with a port number of zero does indeed allocate a free port. This is very basic TCP knowledge, not a controversial claim by the poster. It is for example how an outbound connection gets allocated a free outbound port number.

Comment: @EJP no it's not and it's not *documented* anywhere, what is documented however is that ports smaller than 1024 are *privileged ports* and need privileged access, and if you call listen or connect on an unbound socket it gets bound to a free port, I'd rather count on that than some hack.

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

- Instead of:

  ```
  serv_addr.sin_port = 0;
  ```

  try this:

  ```
  serv_addr.sin_port=htons(2056);//Any port no.
  ```
- Instead of:

  ```
   listen(sock_fd,32);
  ```

  try this:

  ```
   if(listen(sock_fd,SOMAXCONN)<0)//Just to be sure that you are considering max. no. of requests
   {  fprintf(stderr,"error with listen");
      exit(1);}
  ```
- Also for:

  ```
   conn_fd = accept(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr,clilen);
  ```

  Add this:

  ```
   if(conn_fd <0)
   {
     //handle the error here
   }
  ```

If none of these solve your issues, then, there might be problem with the client code or your server environment.

Comment: All good advice, and working through it helped me arrive at the answer that I just posted